# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'amount'

Tags: django

I keep getting the same error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'amount' over and over ever since I added an an amount field to my coupon code script.

This is my code;

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    amount = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

And here's the get_total code;

```
def get_total(self):
    total = 0
    amount = models.FloatField()
    for order_item in self.items.all():
        total += order_item.get_final_price()
    total -= self.coupon.amount
    return total
```

I have been trying to solve this with numerous solutions that didn't work. I would really appreciate it if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Is `get_total` a method of Coupon class? You probably need `self.amount` instead of `self.coupon.amount`. Also, what is the use of `amount = models.FloatField()` in `get_total`?

Comment: get_final_price is a method of OrderItem. Also tried it with self.amount didn't work. It gave me this error; 'Order' object has no attribute 'amount' Also I forgot the amount = models.FloatField() there from before when I was trying to find solutions and without it it still doesn't work

Comment: Correction I meant get_total is a method of Order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you say "get_final_price is a method of OrderItem". I'll assume when you say get_final_price you mean get_total.

Do all OrderItems have a coupon? If `OrderItem.coupon` can be null then you have to change get_total to something like:

```
def get_total(self):
    total = 0
    amount = models.FloatField()
    for order_item in self.items.all():
        total += order_item.get_final_price()
    if self.coupon:
        total -= self.coupon.amount
    return total
```

Comment: Yes sorry I meant get_total it is a method of Order

Answer (score 0):

in models.py all null and blank "true"

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

Comment: Do you mean the error on the webpage or in the terminal?

Comment: webpage will be great

Comment: AttributeError at /order-summary/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'amount'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/order-summary/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'amount'
Exception Location: F:\Users\Kasutaja\Documents\Veebipood v4\django-ecommerce\core\models.py in get_total, line 107